# Using agGroupCellRenderer with custom cell renderer in angular 9

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I want to use custom cell renderer on the column where i have added `colDef`,
`rowGroup = true`.
The custom cell renderer is not displaying the content from html template of cell renderer framework.

When I use `agGroupCellRenderer` it works fine but when i use custom renderer it does not show content.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a cell render component

```
This is the ts file
```

```js
export class AgExpandCellRenderComponent implements OnInit, ICellRendererAngularComp {
  params;
  isExpand: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }
  refresh(params: any): boolean {
    this.isExpand = params.node.expanded;
    return true;
  }
  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
  }
  afterGuiAttached?(params?: IAfterGuiAttachedParams): void {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggleExapnd() {
    this.params.node.setExpanded(!this.isExpand);
    this.isExpand = !this.isExpand;
  }

}
```

This is the template

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <span class="ag-group-expanded" *ngIf="isExpand" (click)="toggleExapnd()" ref="eExpanded"><span
        class="ag-icon ag-icon-expanded" unselectable="on"></span></span>
    <span class="ag-group-contracted" *ngIf="!isExpand" (click)="toggleExapnd()" ref="eContracted"><span
        class="ag-icon ag-icon-contracted" unselectable="on"></span></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    {{You customized content here}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add this component to gridOptions.frameworkComponents like this

```js
frameworkComponents: {
  'ExpandCellRender': AgExpandCellRenderComponent
},
```

Finnally the colDef

```js
{
  field: 'field',
  cellRendererSelector: (params) => {
    return {
        component: 'ExpandCellRender'
    };
},
```

Answer (score 1):

see **Group Cell Renderer Configuration** https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/group-cell-renderer/#group-cell-renderer-configuration

```
const gridOptions = {
columnDefs: [
    // column definition configured to show group values with the cell renderer set to 'group'
    {
        showRowGroup: true,
        cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',
        // provide extra params to the cellRenderer
        cellRendererParams: {
            // turn off the row count
            suppressCount: true,
            // turn off double click for expand
            suppressDoubleClickExpand: true,
            // enable checkbox selection
            checkbox: true,
            // provide an inner renderer
            innerRenderer: myInnerRenderer,
            // provide an inner renderer
            innerRendererParams: {foo: 'bar'},
            // provide a footer value getter
            footerValueGetter: myFooterValueGetter
        }
    }
],

// other grid options ...
```

}

Comment: For me, this is the right answer, the previous answer by @Jun maybe was correct but as for today, this works like a charm.